# How to change URL in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, apache2

How to change URL in Wordpress?

my url in wordpress is

**http://192.168.3.52/iskcon_src/?page_id=75**

I want to change it to
**http://192.168.3.52/iskcon_src/about**

what I have done change in .htaccess file is

**RewriteEngine on**

**RewriteRule /iskcon_src/?page_id=75 /iskcon_src/about****

**It shows The requested URL /iskcon_src/about was not found on this server.**

please help me

Answer (score 2):

have a look on the [wordpress site](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks),

just navigate to your admin, permalinks section, make sure to create your htaccess with write permissions, or copy and paste what wordpress generates at the bottom of the permalinks page afte ryou change the settings..

set your permalink settings to just /%postname%/

[image: Wordpress Permalink setttings]

Answer (score 0):

sudo cp ./mods-available/rewrite.load ./mods-enabled/

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

wordpress permalink will work and it will do itself