# How to change the URL for a webpage created in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, url

On our company website (created with WordPress) we have an articles page with the URL:

`http://example.net/articles`

But when we click on one of those articles, its URL is:

`http://example.net/<some_article_name>`

I just wanted to know how I could change each article's URL to:

`http://example.net/articles/<some_article_name>`

Comment: What kind of elements are these articles? Did you create a custom type called "article"? Please provide more details

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change URL in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481334/how-to-change-url-in-wordpress)

Comment: Hey there, so just to clarify, do you have a page called "Articles" and also custom post types called "Articles"?